# Node.js + Mongoose: Find data and get other data for each

Tags: node.js, express, foreach, mongoose

I have two models Users and News. On the page which is written with Express framework are published news and under the news are comments. Inside News model is subdocument with comments which contains two fields - user (subfields:) { name, objectid } and comment. Because in addition to comment there is user's name, I would like to add some additional informations about it (like number of comments, link to website, ...).

And this is my question: How to get data of user (from Users model) for each comment from subdocument (from News model)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) call to your `find` query to pull in the user details.  I'm not quite clear on your schema, but something like:

```
News.find().populate('comments.userId').exec(...);
```

This relies on your schema defining `userId` as an ObjectId `ref` to `Users`.

Comment: Users and News model are separated, so somehow I need to connect models together. Do I need to create new Users query inside News query which would look like Users.each...?